# Calculate sample size for AB testing when measure matrics has more than one objectives

Tags: sample-size, ab-test

We are launching a new button on our website page. We will use AB testing to see if the new button works.

I can calculate the sample size for AB testing (number of users needed per day) if we only need to test the improvement of **conversion rate**. But meantime in our measure metrics of success, we also want to test before and after difference on two continuous hypotheses: **number massages received and length of browsing.**

I can do sample size calculation for proportion test (conversion rate N1) and two sample t test (messages N2 and time of browsing N3). Should I use the maximum sample size for AB testing (max(N1, N2, N3) if I want to test all three hypotheses with one AB testing experiment.